# How can I mod Minecraft 1.7.9?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I've looked up a lot of tutorials on YouTube and all of them only work for versions of Minecraft prior to 1.7.9.

I first got a Minecraft Coder Pack (MCP) off of [this website](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/download.php?list.2), but then realized that only decompiles Minecraft 1.6.4. Then I found a more recent MCP (that's not on the website for some reason) and it is version 9.03, downloaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/q97ptg3ng85tpra/mcp903.zip). This decompiles Minecraft version 1.7.2 (when I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lsv-S9--Z8)'s instructions, I run the decompile.bat file and it says `Json file not found in C:\Users\mike\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.2\1.7.2.json`).

Basically I can't decompile Minecraft 1.7.9, but I can decompile older versions. However, I don't have any older versions downloaded onto my computer. I have only 1.7.9.

Then I tried using Forge, but realized that most videos were using versions of Minecraft prior to 1.6.4, meaning they use the bin folder that does not exist anymore. Even after trying to figure that out as well, the decompiling would never work. I tried to do what [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klYTEMiATZw) did, but couldn't replicate it. Then I finally looked at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkRAW7gTnWw) about using Forge and I could replicate it, but this didn't decompile Minecraft. It just set up a workspace in Eclipse that I'm not sure how to use.

**TL;DR**

**I can decompile Minecraft 1.6.4 and 1.7.2 but I can't decompile version 1.7.9. Should I download an older version of Minecraft, wait for an MCP for 1.7.9, or something else? Is there something I'm missing, where I actually can decompile and mod Minecraft 1.7.9?**

Comment: This question is so specific it's unlikely to help many people -1.

Comment: @Byte56 How is this so specific? It's how to mod the latest version of Minecraft. The question is do you mod an earlier version instead, or is there a way to mod the current version of Minecraft? What a stupid reason to downvote. A lot of people want to know this. I see it on countless other Minecraft forums without answers.

Comment: Tell me again how it's not specific in 6 months or a year. Further, it's apparently something that's pretty easy to learn by reading the documentation. One of the reasons to downvote is "not useful", I believe this question falls under that category. Sorry you think it's a stupid reason, it's not personal though.

Comment: @Byte56 So what, we shouldn't ask questions about the current version of a development project because there will be a new one later? With that attitude, nothing would every be solved for *any* version. That's ridiculous. And a lot of things are easy to learn by reading the documentation. Go on StackOverflow and look at some of the popular questions. And how am I supposed to look up documentation on something I don't know exists? I was hoping there was other software to decompile. This is a useful question. I don't care if it's personal, it's a stupid and unjust reason to downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MCP 9.03 RC1 for Minecraft 1.7.2](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/news.php?extend.11.1):

> This version of MCP works for Minecraft 1.7.2 only. A version for
>   newer 1.7.x version will be released eventually.

Even if you do modify the ***~\conf\version.cfg*** file to look for 1.7.9 versions it fails (version 1.7.9 contains Twitch integration that 1.7.2 does not).  I dare say there are many other significant differences from 1.7.2 to 1.7.9.  It looks like we will just have to wait until the **MCP** people do their magic.

Comment: Thank you. All I wanted was for someone to confirm I had to wait.